# Lightning Web Components - track user (insert visit record) after login

Tags: community, lightning-web-components, create-records, lwc-wire-adapter

We use lightning communities. I am working on building a new LWC component, where I can place it in the page footer. The goal of the component is simple: once the user logs in, visits a page in the community - capture user info and network info and insert the information in a custom object.

I am using [createrecord](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.data_salesforce_write) wire service to insert a new record. On research, I found out that I have 2 options for lifecycle hooks. `renderedCallback()` or `connectedCallback()`. `renderedCallback()` does insert the record but it runs multiple times; tried to use `initialRender` but with no luck. `connectedCallback()` does not create the record.

What is the recommended approach so that a visit can be captured?

Comment: Worth noting that Salesforce outlined new analytics abilities, including login, to come ("safe harbor" declared) in Winter '20 release. You may find that you implement a load of custom stuff that becomes OOTB at that point.

Comment: NB: You may also be facing GDPR issues if you capture user-identifiable details.

Comment: Thank you! Ignoring the analytics and purely to learn LWC, could you let me know on the best way to insert a record when the component is loaded/rendered?

Comment: @gkolan Are you saying that you are not able to utilize a private member to determine if `renderedCallback()` has already executed as mentioned in the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_lifecycle_hooks_rendered)?

Comment: have you tried making the save call in the component constructor?

Comment: I pushed all the logic to the Apex class method which inserts the record information. It solved the issue. I needed the current user id, network id, and today's date. Apex solved it for me! The apex class method was called from renderedCallback()